# what are all different types of relationship in mysql

Tags: mysql

Ok I am aware of one to one- one to many- many to many.

My question is can you have one to one optional and mandatory relationship.
Can you have one to many optional and many relationships.

Where is the best resource for me learning about the different types of relationship in mysql.

Comment: I'm guessing that optional just means that your Foreign Key can be null.

Comment: i thought it was bad practice to do a null join though

Comment: A "null join?"  You can do a join, either inner or outer.  The inner join will exclude records that do not have a corresponding match on both sides, including the ones will null in the FK.

Comment: i thought this broke data intergrity

Comment: Optional is as optional does. Consider a field on a survey, where the user does not pull down the combo box and specify a value from the list. You can either leave the field `null`, or force it to a "did not specify" value (a value that is not really a value; a magic value that you now have to add to the related table). Which one best satisfies Occam's Razor?

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was better practice to create a join on table in this instance when a optional can be null. The join table would reference with drop down option and the other column would represent the customer. Rather than store nulls. I thought in effect storing null goes against referential intergrity.